# ProGuard - How to use correctly for Android ? Which classes and libraries to keep?

Tags: android, android-proguard

I am trying to improve my understanding about usage of ProGuard for Android build. Am not  very sure what to keep ( not obfuscate ) exactly and what to obfuscate.

Couple of libraries are being used in my App, some of them are listed below

```
com.android.support:appcompat
com.android.support:design
io.reactivex:rxandroid
io.reactivex:rxjava 
com.jakewharton.rxbinding
com.trello:rxlifecycle
```

**Question 1:**

Should I obfuscate above libraries ? they are already open source.. will it not be wise to keep all support libraries using proguard rule:

`keep class android.support.** { *; }`

Similar way I can do with io.reactivex and jakewharton libraries

**Question 2**

Other than support and external libraries, I have application specific classes, coded for this application. Is it ok to keep the class names which are mentioned in AndroidManifest.xml and specifically their public members, and let obfuscate rest of the code.

Let me know if I am missing something or my understanding is not correct. just to repeat this is not a question on  how to do it technically, but more on  what to include and what to exclude  for obfuscation/optimization/ shrink..  and more specifically reason behind it ....Definitely it will be espresso tested after build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1: Should I obfuscate above libraries?

Yes. If you add `-keep <library>` rules then the entire library will be included in your APK, which bloats it and might cause problems such as making your app exceed the 64k method limit and require Multidex. It's always a good idea to apply the ProGuard rules provided by the library. You can usually find `.pro` files in the libraries source code or in websites such as https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets.

> Question 2: Is it ok to keep the class names which are mentioned in AndroidManifest.xml and specifically their public members, and let obfuscate rest of the code.

The Android plugin already does that for you. The plugin scans all classes whose names need to be preserved (e.g. Activities, Services, BroadcastReceivers, Views, etc) and doesn't obfuscate them. This includes everything that you declare in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Thanks, I had overlooked ProGuard's shrinking option.. agree we can refer relevant sites for respective ProGuard configuration.. but how about Google Specific Libraries..i.e. com.android.support:appcompat where we can find config for the those ..   Regarding your answer for question 2 for application specific code... Do you mean.. we should not provide any settings.. for our own code..? and in this case.. application specific code.. which is mentioned in AndroidManifest is always out in open for decompile.. ?

Comment: Some libraries, namely `com.android.support:appcompat`, don't need explicit rules to work with ProGuard as the default configuration that Android Plugin specifies already catches all edge cases (e.g. Views, Fragments), while other libraries (like `rxjava`) may need explicit rules. It varies from case to case and the best thing to do is check the documentation of each library for a section about ProGuard rules.

Comment: Regarding "our own code", the default configuration in the Android Plugin already specifies lots of rules that will be applied to your app. By enabling "minify", ProGuard will already obfuscate as much as possible. But you're right about AndroidManifest.. certain classes/methods/fields can't be obfuscated effectively (e.g. `Activity.onCreate(Bundle)` will always be called that because it's invoked externally) so one trick you do is move as much code as possible out of your activities/fragments/views into separate helper objects and then let ProGuard obfuscate them :)